# Mixing libraries from different C++ compilers

Tags: c++, linux, compiler-construction, compatibility

I am working on redhat 5.2 on a project which spans several disparate organizations.  Each organization delivers libraries which have been compiled with various versions of g++.  Currently, these versions include 4.1.1, 4.1.2 and 4.3.1.  I am trying to link all the libraries together into an executable using 4.1.2.  What, if any, problems may I expect by doing this?  As an aside, is there a way to tell which ABI each compiler version builds to?

Comment: At first I thought you meant Red Hat 5.2 (Apollo), which is over ten years old. :)

Answer (score 6):

This [ABI](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/abi.html) policy document details the compatibility between different ABI versions.
According to that, the `libstdc++.so` library should be compatible, and the last time gcc broke binary compatibility was at 3.4. You should be fine.

Answer (score 5):

GCC (GNU Compiler Collection) defines version numbers and compatibility.

The G++ libraries between 4.1.1 and 4.1.2 should be compatible; link with the newest.

The G++ libraries between 4.1.x and 4.2.x are not compatible; you need to recompile something.

The G++ libraries between 3.x.y and 4.p.q are not compatible; you need to recompile something.

In your scenario, the code built with 4.3.1 is not compatible with the rest.

Either you will have to rebuild the code currently compiled with 4.3.x so it uses 4.1.x, or you need to recompile the code currently compiled with 4.1.x so it uses 4.3.x instead.

Comment: That is the theory, but in the practice the last ABI change was 3.4

Comment: @Edu: but at any time in the future, there could be a change which invokes that rule, and people who have gotten sloppy about things may be in for a surprise (having to recompile).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is easier to static link the executable... makes a big binary, but runs on all platforms.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no problems linking libraries built from different versions of g++ unless they've been listed on the g++ website. What is important though is that these libraries be built on the same platform which in your case is redhat 5.2. A library built for a platform other than linux/redhat (say solaris) will not link with your exe.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, there is a C++ compatibility library that is used to do just that.  I think it's called **libstdc++-compat**.

Comment: You can't link together objects which depend on different versions of stdlibc++.